# Does water become cooler when temperature increase so rate of evaporation increase?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, cooling

We say rate of evaporation increase with increase in temperature either surrounding or of liquid!

Does increased rate of evaporation due to increase in temperature cause increase in cooling?

Because if I keep water vessel in sunshine , instead of being cool it become hot although rate of evaporation increase with temperature!

Answer (score 0):

Because the temperature is an average of all the particle's energy we do have individual particles taking some energy away from the system and the probability of the particles leaving increases as the energy increases, but the increase in energy adds to the energy of most of the particles so you tend to have an increase in the average kinetic energy till the point where you need to you cant increase the kinetic energy anymore until they have to overcome the potential energy to reach the next state.

So in a microscopic point of view, you have energy loss from the rest of the liquid with the evaporation(it cools the liquid) but the energy of the entire system is increasing with increase heat applied(the entire liquid is heating up)

[image]